# Attempting to get a value from a JSON Object freezes task

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net

I have a lyrics app where I need to download the lyrics from all songs in a Spotify library. This process has 3 functions: the first calls the Spotify API to retrieve the list of songs and saves that to a list; the second calls the Genius API to search on their database and attempts to find a song with matching title and artist; the third calls the Genius API again to get song details like album name and featured artists and also loads the page containing the lyrics to then save everything into a file.

Problem is that for some reason, whenever the JSON parser (from JSON.NET) finds a null value it freezes the entire task, without throwing an exception or anything. I have basically this same code implement in my Main Activity and whenever there's a null value it just returns an empty string. For whatever reason this time it simply refuses to keep going.

Here's the code from part of the third function:

```cs
private async Task getDetails(string APIPath)
{
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Starting getDetails operation");
    string results = await Genius.GetSongDetails(APIPath, "Bearer my_apps_auth_code"); //This method gives a "Reading content stream..." message
    JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(results);                                           //on the log when it recieves a JSON from the API

    Song song = new Song() //This is a custom class to store song information throught the app.
    {
        title = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["title"],
        artist = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["primary_artist"]["name"],
        album = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["album"]["name"],
        header = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["header_image_url"],
        cover = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["song_art_image_url"],
        APIPath = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["api_path"],
        path = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["path"]
    }; //This is where it gets stuck. You can see in the log file that it recieves the JSON from the API but never processes it.

    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Created new Song variable");

    if (parsed["response"]["song"]["featured_artists"].HasValues)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Track has featured artists");
        //... 
    }
    else
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Track does not have featured artists");
        song.featuredArtist = "";
    }

    string downloadedLyrics;

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Trying to load page");
    var doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync("https://genius.com" + song.path);
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Verbose, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Loaded Genius page");
    var lyricsBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='lyrics']");

    downloadedLyrics = Regex.Replace(lyricsBody.InnerText, @"^\s*", ""); //these regexes just removes some
    downloadedLyrics = Regex.Replace(downloadedLyrics, @"[\s]+$", "");  //whitespace on the start and end of the lyrics
    song.lyrics = downloadedLyrics;

    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "SmartLyrics", "getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Completed getDetails task for " + song.APIPath);
}
```

This method gets called 3 times in a row, and there's another function that checks if the last 3 calls are done or not before calling it three more times.

Here's the LogCat:

```
06-26 14:26:21.189: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): No tasks are running!

06-26 14:26:21.189: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Starting getDetails operation
06-26 14:26:21.190: V/SmartLyrics(31087): GeniusRequests.cs: Adding Auth headers to HttpClient
06-26 14:26:21.190: W/SmartLyrics(31087): Url sent to HttpClient: https://api.genius.com/songs/3393276
06-26 14:26:21.193: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): foreach for index 4 completed.

06-26 14:26:21.193: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Starting getDetails operation
06-26 14:26:21.194: V/SmartLyrics(31087): GeniusRequests.cs: Adding Auth headers to HttpClient
06-26 14:26:21.194: W/SmartLyrics(31087): Url sent to HttpClient: https://api.genius.com/songs/3125896
06-26 14:26:21.195: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): foreach for index 5 completed.

06-26 14:26:21.196: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Starting getDetails operation
06-26 14:26:21.196: V/SmartLyrics(31087): GeniusRequests.cs: Adding Auth headers to HttpClient
06-26 14:26:21.196: W/SmartLyrics(31087): Url sent to HttpClient: https://api.genius.com/songs/2822309
06-26 14:26:21.198: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): foreach for index 6 completed. //All three calls made, now it will wait until all of them are finished to call three more

06-26 14:26:21.198: E/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): getDetails tasks still running //This is from a while loop that checks if all tasks have finished.
06-26 14:26:21.958: V/SmartLyrics(31087): GeniusRequests.cs: Reading content stream... //1
06-26 14:26:21.968: D/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Created new Song variable
06-26 14:26:21.968: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Track does not have featured artists
06-26 14:26:21.968: D/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Trying to load page
06-26 14:26:21.972: V/SmartLyrics(31087): GeniusRequests.cs: Reading content stream... //2
06-26 14:26:22.536: V/SmartLyrics(31087): GeniusRequests.cs: Reading content stream... //3 This means that all 3 of them recieved a response from the API
06-26 14:26:22.540: D/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Created new Song variable
06-26 14:26:22.540: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Track does not have featured artists
06-26 14:26:22.540: D/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Trying to load page
06-26 14:26:24.618: V/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Loaded Genius page
06-26 14:26:24.619: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Completed getDetails task for /songs/3393276 //1
06-26 14:26:24.850: V/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Loaded Genius page
06-26 14:26:24.852: I/SmartLyrics(31087): getDetails (SpotifyDownload): Completed getDetails task for /songs/3125896 //2 Only two of the three finished.
06-26 14:26:26.199: E/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): getDetails tasks still running
06-26 14:26:31.200: E/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): getDetails tasks still running
06-26 14:26:36.201: E/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): getDetails tasks still running
06-26 14:26:41.202: E/SmartLyrics(31087): getGeniusSearchResults (SpotifyDownload): getDetails tasks still running //It gets stuck in a loop here because the getDetails method never fiishes.
```

The only song that gets stuck is one that has a null value on the "album" object. Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `album` is null, you're probably getting a `NullReferenceException` on this line and something isn't handling it well:

```
album = (string)parsed["response"]["song"]["album"]["name"],
```

Try using `SelectToken()` instead of a chain of square brackets:

```
album = (string)parsed.SelectToken("response.song.album.name");
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work fine. Do you have an idea of what could be prohibiting the app from showing an exception?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't.